# Jetpack Compose: Passing slider value out of row function

Tags: kotlin, environment-variables, slider, android-jetpack-compose, global-variables

I am using standard composable elements to build an app and trying to access Slider values in another part of the function. The compiler doesn't see the Slider variable outside of the Row element, returning "Unresolved reference". How else can I define the Slider variable so I can access it globally? I read environmental variables might be more suitable.

The values are logged correctly in MainActivity Log.d.

I've tried defining the Slider variable in different parts of the @Composable, but I'm unsure how to access the variable outside of the ui elements.

````
 Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp, bottom = 5.dp)
                .height(50.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                .background(color = Color(0xFF373737).copy(alpha = 0.3f))
                .border(2.dp, SolidColor(Color(0xFF3C3C3C)), shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {

            var sliderValueP1 by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            Box (

            ){
                Slider(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 15.dp, top = 20.dp, end = 15.dp),
                    value = sliderValueP1,
                    onValueChange = { sliderValue_ ->
                        sliderValueP1 = sliderValue_
                    },
                    onValueChangeFinished = {
                        // this is called when the user completed selecting the value
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "sliderValueP1 = ${sliderValueP1.roundToInt()}")
                    },
                    valueRange = 0f..130f,
                    // steps = 170,
                    colors = SliderDefaults.colors(
                        thumbColor = Color(0xFF00B3D4),
                        activeTrackColor = Color(0xFF00B3D4),
                        inactiveTrackColor = Color(0xFF3C3C3C)
                    )
                )```
````

Comment: What do you mean by "another part of function" ? Another part of current composable or another part of whole application ? Since you also said "globally access" it is causing an ambiguity.

Comment: Apologies - I'd like to use the slider value as input to a graph on the same screen, so I think that's "different function, same composable"

Comment: Then, you can create your state variable on the top of the parent composable and pass it to necessary functions UNLESS you want to use that state value on another part of your application. In that case i suggest you to create a state data class which holds your all ui state information and then store that UiState in your viewmodel and access it via viewmodel instance that you will create in your Composables or NavGraphs. Here is a [sample](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-jetpack-compose-store-information-using-state-class-and-data-class/)